# Semantic Release publishing on package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-actions, npm-publish, semantic-release

I am currently try to auto publish my npm package to GitHub packages using semantic release with GitHub Actions. The package publishes successfully but when Installed, only the `package.json` file is found in the published package.

I have a build command that builds my package into a `dist` folder and would like to publish the contents of the dist folder to GitHub packages.

Below are the configuration files for the package release and GitHub Actions workflow

The workflow below runs the test and creates a new release to GitHub Packages

**test-publish.yml**

```
name: Test and Publish
on:
  push:
    branches: 'main'
    paths-ignore:
      - .gitignore
      - README.md

jobs:
  test-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Check for forgotten it.only in unit tests
        run: "! git grep -F 'it.only' -- src/__tests__"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
      - name: Run Tests
        run: yarn test
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
      - name: Prepare Publish to NPM
        run: yarn run preparePub
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
      - name: Release
        run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN_NPM: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Below is the package.json
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@organisation/component-library",
  "version": "0.0.0-semantic-release",
  "author": "Author Name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "Component library",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/organisation/component-library.git"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && yarn run prettier --write src/ && yarn run lint && yarn build:esm && yarn build:cjs",
    "build:cjs": "tsc --module CommonJS --OutDir dist/cjs",
    "build:esm": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts src/**/*.tsx",
    "test": "jest",
    "preparePub": "yarn run build &&  cp package.json dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer": "^9.0.2",
    "@semantic-release/github": "^8.0.6",
    "@semantic-release/npm": "^9.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator": "^10.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.15",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "*"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn run lint && git add -A ."
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  }
}
```

The `preparePub` script is used to build the library and copy the package.json file to the list folder

Below is the semantic release config file where I set the package root to dist
**.releaserc**

```
{
  "branches": [
    "main",
    {
      "name": "beta",
      "prerelease": true
    }
  ],
  "repositoryUrl": "https://github.com/organisation/component-library",
  "debug": "true",
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
      "@semantic-release/npm",
      {
        "pkgRoot": "dist"
      }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/github"
  ]
}
```

***tsconfig.json***

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "DOM", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/esm",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/jest.setup.ts"]
}
```

The issue here is that the GitHub Actions pipeline seem to work fine but after the package is released to GitHub packages and installed in whatever app I want to use the library, only the `package.json` file is found within the installed library and none of the contents of the list folder.

Comment: The `npm pack` command lists files that it will include in the package. Have you checked its output that it lists all the files you expect to be included when it is run?

Comment: You mean the outDir in the tsconfig?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but does your build script work locally?

Comment: Yes I does. Generate esm and cjs folder in dist with all the need files

Comment: In that case, go carefully read the messages and status reports from the execution of your GitHub action and try to find anything that indicates what went wrong. Then come back and provide us with as much of that relevant information as you can. If your repo is public and you are okay with sharing it here, give us a link to the GitHub action execution.

Comment: What does your tsconfig look like and why are you using PascalCase `--OutDir`?

Comment: I have added the tsconfig edit @morganney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `pkgRoot` in `.releaserc`. Instead of setting it to `dist`, I set to `dist/` and it somehow worked. Funny thing is, I have configured with just `dist` before and it worked. Thank you all for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you build locally, you have a `build` folder with package.json and a cjs folder, but only the file itself is coming through (since that's what I did in the past).

Try having your package.json `files` property look like this instead:

```
"files": [
  "dist/*"
],
```

That's what I needed to get it to publish folders as well.

Comment: Thanks @Julianna, I tried this but It still didn't work

Comment: Thanks @Julianna, I tried this but It still didn't work